# Sublime Text : Open folder in new window instead of the current one

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using sublime text 3 on Mac OS.

When I have one tab open and try to open a folder, it gets opened in the same window. Like this:

[image: Sublime Text 3]

How can I change this behaviour to open a new folder in a new window instead?

Comment: More recent versions of MacOS try to create a tab bar in open windows instead of many windows, so this is a MacOS specific thing and not a setting in MacOS per se. I don't run that version of MacOS but I believe if you look under `Dock` in the system preferences, you can change the setting for "Prefer tabs when opening documents" to "Manually" to stop this from happening.

Comment: Also currently Sublime themes that custom color the window caption (for example the build in `Adaptive` theme) block this from happening, so that's another way around this, although this may not be a permanent solution if the Sublime Devs are able to work around why MacOS is disabling window tabs in that case.

Comment: Great. Changing dock settings works here. Thanks a lot.
Why don't you write it as an answer so I can mark it accepted.

Comment: Done; sorry for the delay, it's been a busy week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Natively Sublime only knows how to open tabs for individual files, so what you're seeing here is something that is a feature of more recent versions of MacOS, which tries to group all of the windows for an application together into one window by providing an extra row of tabs under the window title bar.

In order to disable this, you will need to modify your dock settings. I'm running an older version of MacOS that doesn't have this feature, but I'm told that in `System Preferences > Dock` there is a setting for something like `Prefer tabs when opening documents` whose setting you can change to stop this from happening.

In addition, one of the recent improvements in Sublime Text 3 are enhancements to the theme engine that allow theme authors to style how the application presents itself. One of the enhancements allows the theme to change the color of the window caption to match the rest of the window.

Due to the way MacOS implements the window tab feature, using a theme that does this (an example is the `Adaptive` theme that ships with Sublime) also has the effect of causing MacOS to automatically disable window tabs for that particular application.

For anyone that happens across this question wanting the reverse of what you want for whom changing the above setting doesn't work, the solution to actually having the tabs appear is to use a different theme that doesn't change the window caption color (or modify your theme accordingly).